# Reading An Image using Jimp

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read an image using Jimp and I keep receiving the same error over and over although I've seen a lot of people and tutorials doing the exact same thing, so can someone please give me an explanation of why is this error happening? I'm calling the read function from wow.js. Thank you very much in advance

EDIT: If I replace the relative path with the absolute path, it seems to work, but I've seen other people use the relative path normally, so can someone tell me why it's not working? Thanks :)

Error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'wow.png'`

My Code:
`const wow = Jimp.read('wow.png');`
and this is my folder setup: 
[image]

Comment: How is this code being run? Did you try `"./wow.png"`?

Comment: I'm running it using node, the command im using is node index.js

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more context or concrete steps on how to reproduce this if you haven't solved it at this point. Does opening any other file in the directory with `fs.readFile` work, for example?